# Is there a better way to write the following jq script?

Tags: jq

```
{   
      "k1": {
        "i1": 11,
        "i2": 10,
        "b1": {
          "p1": 101,
          "p2": 102,
          "p3": 103
        },
        "b2": {
          "r1": "k1vr1",
          "r2": "k1vr2"
        }   
      },   
      "k2": {
        "i1": 21,
        "i2": 20,
        "b1": {
          "p1": 201,
          "p2": 202,
          "p3": 203
        },
        "b2": {
          "r1": "k2vr1",
          "r2": "k2vr2",
          "r3": "k2vr3"
        }   
       },   
       "k3": {
        "i1": 51,
        "i2": 50,
        "i3": 70,
        "b1": {
          "p1": 301,
          "p2": 302,
          "p3": 303
        },
        "b2": {
          "r1": "k3vr1",
          "r2": "k3vr2",
          "r3": "k3vr3"
        }   
      } 
}
```

I have a json document with a huge number objects following the above pattern. I need to create following output document using **jq**.

```
{
  "k2": {
    "b2": {
      "r3": "k2vr3"
    }
  },
  "k3": {
    "i3": 70,
    "b2": {
      "r3": "k3vr3"
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to create the output using the following jq script

```
map_values(select(.i2 >= 20 and .b1.p2 > 150) | {i3: .i3, b2:{r3: .b2.r3}} | map_values(select(. != null)))
```

I would like to know if there is a better, faster and generalized script?

Comment: You could shorten `i3: .i3` to just `i3`, and `select(. != null)` to `values`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid various inefficiencies in your program, consider replacing

```
 {i3: .i3, b2:{r3: .b2.r3}}
```

With:

```
 (((select(.i3)|{i3}) // null) + { b2: {r3: .b2.r3}} )
```

That would obviate the need for the second call to `map_values`

Comment: The above code doesn't return the intended output. Key value "k2" is filtered. .k2.i3 is not there in "k2".

Comment: @kishore - Thanks for pointing out the need for //